# Facebook Graph API Sync Photo Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to sync a photo album to a facebook group album.  When using a token as a user with moderator permissions I can view and post photos to the album using 
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{album_id}/photos
and
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{album_id}/photos

However, when I go to delete photos I get:

```
"(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead."
```

With the recent changes to the api and removal of publish_actions is there anyway to delete photos in group albums?  Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Did you try `publish_to_groups` permission?

Comment: Yes.  I need the publish_to_groups to be able to post new photos.  Thanks!